# Error in Azure Storage Explorer with Azurite : The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-storage, azurite, azure-storage-explorer

I'm running an Azure function locally, from VSCode, that outputs a string to a blob. I'm using Azurite to emulate the output blob container.
My function looks like this:

```
import azure.functions as func

def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest, outputblob:func.Out[str]):
    outputblob.set("hello")
```

My function.json:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mytimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 * * * * *"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputblob",
      "type": "blob",
      "dataType": "string",
      "direction": "out",
      "path": "testblob/hello"
    }
  ]
}
```

In local.settings.json, I've set `"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"`.

The problem is, when I run the function and check in Azure Storage Explorer, the container is created (testblob) (along with 2 other containers: azure-webjobs-hosts and azure-webjobs-secrets) but it is empty and Azure Storage Explorer displays an error message when I refresh :
**The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object.Received undefined**

The function runs and doesn't return any error message.

When I use a queue instead of a blob as output, it works and I can see the string in the emulated queue storage.

When I use the blob storage in my Azure subscription instead of the emulated blob, it works as well, a new blob is created with the string.

I've tried the following:

- clean and restart Azurite several times
- replace `"UseDevelopmentStorage=true"` by the connection string of the emulated storage
- reinstall Azure Storage Explorer

I keep getting the same error message.

I'm using Azure Storage Explorer Version 1.25.0 on Windows 11.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It looks like this is a known issue: https://github.com/microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/issues/6008

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like this is a known issue with the latest release (v1.25.0) of Azure Storage Explorer version see:
https://github.com/microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/issues/6008

Simplest solution is to uninstall and re-install an earlier version:
https://github.com/microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/releases/tag/v1.24.3

Comment: Thank you! I should have suspected this was a bug.

Comment: Not fixed in v1.25.1 yet

Comment: According to the GitHub issues this should be fixed in v1.26.0 can anyone confirm?

Comment: For me fixed in 1.27.0